# how can I transfer nokia lumia 8 data to samsung galaxy 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-transfer, windows-mobile

how can I transfer nokia lumia 8 data to samsung galaxy 3
I tried Transgo the usb cables would not connect to the PC even after I bought good quality cables.

Comment: What data specifically do you expect to transfer from Lumia to Samsung?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this app to share your contacts.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/qontact/e3404be4-324f-46e3-b47d-5561c676cad6

You Can Also Sync your Contacts between Lumia 820 & Galaxy S4 using your Hotmail ID. Just login your Hotmail ID to your galaxy S4 and Sync.

You Can Export Your Contact from https://people.live.com using your hotmail id in *.csv format then import in your Phone or Google Account Which you are using in Galaxy S4.

From [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-do-i-transfer-my-contacts-to-android-phone/ca90c5f3-3e88-4990-a870-7bbdfc3c725e?auth=1)

Comment: Android Contacts has no support for .csv format. Instead .vcf files are imported into the contacts list. So if there is an option to export vcf format please update you question. Else suggest another option for importing the data. Also please explain on "How to" part of importing/exporting the contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions:

1. Download an app which can make a backup of your Contacts in a `.vcf` file.
2. Copy this file and paste it into your Android phone storage.
3. Click this file from your Android phone. It will automatically export the contacts to your contact list.

Alternatively, download [SHAREit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps) app in both phones. Then send your contacts from one phone to another.

Comment: No. Android won't automatically import .vcf files when opened. You need to import them in your Contacts app manually by selecting Import option. And OP asks for data transfer and not specifically just for contact. So this only partly answers the question.

Comment: its not necessary  or it depends on android version . in kitkat & upper it will automatically restore your contacts when you click on it.